# How do I unit test RxJava Completable doOnSuccess function?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, rx-java

I have seen how to test observable using `TestSubscriber` but I have no idea how to test `Completable.doOnSuccess` callback. Specifically this method:

```
fun setAuthToken(authToken: AuthToken): Completable {
    this.authToken = authToken

    return Completable.fromSingle<User>(api
            .getCurrentUser()
            .doOnSuccess {
                user = it
            })
}
```

Comment: It makes no sense. Completable does not have a value thus it can't succeed, only complete. Keep the `Single<User>` type and work with that.

Comment: What exactly do you want to test here?

Comment: @akarnokd it does make sense. That is `doOnSuccess` of the Single but I am returning a Completable because the caller of this function only cares whether or not it succeeded, not the result

Comment: @michalbrz I want to test the user is set after after setting the auth token

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not something that might not need to be tested with RxJava test subscribers at all (depending on the rest of the code).

Remember - **you don't want to test internal state**, or at least do it as rarely as possible. Internal state and class structure can change and it will probably change often. So it's bad practice to check if user is assigned to the field.

So you *could* make `Completable` blocking and then assert state of (let’s call it ‚server’) server class, but **I would highly discourage doing it this way:**

```
server.setAuthToken(AuthToken("token"))
            .blockingAwait()
assertThat(server.user, equalTo(expectedUser))
```

**What you want to test is behavior.**

You are probably not assigning user to the field just for the sake of having some fields. You are doing it to use information from user later on. So first you should call setAuthToken and **then call function that really uses information from the user.** Then you can assert if used information is correct and is coming from correct user.

So sample tests (depending on the class) could look like this:

```
server.setAuthToken(AuthToken("token"))
        .andThen(server.sendRequest())
        .blockingAwait()
    // assert if correct user info was sent
```

or

```
server.setAuthToken(AuthToken("token"))
    .andThen(server.sendRequest())
    .test()
    // assert if correct user info was sent
```

Comment: That is what I was trying to do, but in my case the user is fetched because some calls to server rely on the user id. The problem is, since I am mocking server it isnt really checking if the userId is correct. If for some reason the userId failed to be set, this wouldnt be picked up at all in unit tests.

Comment: I think that is exactly what should be done in this case - check if server  receives correct userId. How you do it - if it is local server communicating via http or just mocked class is just the detail. But at least then you check if your classes *function* correctly without depending on their structure.

Comment: I am just mocking the retrofit interface of the api. Thank you for the help though I think I will try that!